# Search multidimensional array in PHP and return keys

Tags: php, search, multidimensional-array

I'm facing following issue: I've set up a website representing an "Icon Library". It basically shows the contents of a CSV file containing additional attributes for an icon, e.g.

- File name
- Tooltip
- Tags
- State (done, in progress)
- File types

  - png

    - File name found in directory
  - eps

    - File name found in directory
  - ico

    - File name found in directory
  - ...

In the end everything is put into a big array:

```
[390] => Array
    (
        [0] => hammer
        [1] => Properties
        [2] => tools, hammer, properties
        [3] => 
        [4] => done
        [png] => Array
            (
                [0] => hammer_16x.png
                [1] => hammer_32x.png
            )

        [eps] => Array
            (
                [0] => hammer_16x.eps
                [1] => hammer_32x.eps
            )

        [ico] => Array
            (
                [0] => hammer.ico
            )

    )
```

Now I would like to provide the possibility to search in this array and filter the contents displayed on the website based on the search result. Therefore I would like to search at least for following strings:

```
 [0] => hammer
 [1] => Properties
 [2] => tools, hammer, properties
 [3] => 
 [4] => done
```

Any hints how I could do that?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Write a bunch of `foreach` loops, what else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `array_filter` in conjunction with `array_diff_assoc`.
Somehow like this:

```
function filter($array, $filter_elem) {
    return array_filter($array, function ($v) use($filter_elem) {
        return count(array_diff_assoc($filter_elem, $v)) == 0;
    });
}

$array = array(
    '390' => array(
        '0' => 'hammer',
        '1' => 'Properties',
        '2' => 'tools, hammer, properties',
        '3' => false,
        '4' => 'done',
        'png' => array(
            '0' => 'hammer_16x.png',
            '1' => 'hammer_32x.png',
        ),
        'eps' => array(
            '0' => 'hammer_16x.eps',
            '1' => 'hammer_32x.eps',
        ),
        'ico' => array(
            '0' => 'hammer.ico',
        ),
    ),
    ...
);

$filter_elem = array(
    '1' => 'Properties',
    '2' => 'tools, hammer, properties',
    '3' => false,
    '4' => 'done',
);

print_r(filter($array, $filter_elem));
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/9WzMIS)

Comment: Hi! This is a cool approach :) I tested it! What I would like to try in addition is using wild cards (e.g. preg_filter?) so that the result above is also shown when just searching for e.g. "amm". But what I've tried now using your code does not work :/

Comment: This is another problem (question). I have solved your problem as it was described in the original question. You have to acknowledge my answer as a solution first. Then you may ask another question(s).

Comment: You are right. This I did not mention explicitly! Thanks for your support!

Comment: Related to this issue I've now added this additional question (especially focusing usage of regex): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22381434/search-multidimensional-array-using-regular-expressions-in-php-and-return-keys

Answer (score 0):

An elegant and reusable way to go about it.

### Implementation:

```
class FilterableArrayCollection implements ArrayAccess
{
    /**
     *    The original $data from your array it contains the $items to be sorted.
     * The items in this array are sorted in the original order you received/read
     * them in.
     */
    protected $data  = array();

    /**
     *    A hash structured as key/subkeys/items
     * - the key is an index name -- the name of a property you have in each item
     *   from the original data;
     * - the subkeys are the value of the property from each item;
     * - the items are variable references to items who respect the rule
     *   $item[$key] === $subkey
     */
    protected $index = array();

    public function __construct(array $data = array())
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function findBy($filter, $value, $isUnique = true)
    {
        if (!isset($this->index[$filter]) {
            foreach ($this->data as $item) {
                $currentValue = $item[$filter];

                if ($isUnique) {
                    $this->index[$filter][$currentValue] = &$item;
                } else {
                    $this->index[$filter][$currentValue][] = &$item;
                }
            }
            ksort($this->index[$filter]);
        } else {
            return($this->index[$filter][$value]);
        }
    }

/*
 * Implement ArrayAccess interface here
 */
}
```

### Example:

```
$data = array(
    array(
        'filename' => 'hammer',
        'tooltip' => 'Properties',
        'tags' => 'tools, hammer, properties',
        'state' => 'done',
        'filetypes' => array(
            'png' => array(
                'hammer_16x.png',
                'hammer_32x.png'
            ),
            'eps' => array(
                'hammer_16x.eps',
                'hammer_32x.eps'
            ),
            'ico' => array(
                'hammer.ico'
            )
        )
    ),
    array(
        'filename' => 'hammer',
        'tooltip' => 'not-Properties',
        'tags' => 'tools, hammer, properties',
        'state' => 'in progress',
        'filetypes' => array(
            'png' => array(
                'hammer_16x.png',
                'hammer_32x.png'
            ),
            'eps' => array(
                'hammer_16x.eps',
                'hammer_32x.eps'
            ),
            'ico' => array(
                'hammer.ico'
            )
        )
    )
);

$x = new FilterableArrayCollection($data);
$filtered = $x->findBy('state', 'done');
var_dump($filtered);

/**
array(
        'filename' => 'hammer',
        'tooltip' => 'Properties',
        'tags' => 'tools, hammer, properties',
        'state' => 'done',
        'filetypes' => array(
            'png' => array(
                'hammer_16x.png',
                'hammer_32x.png'
            ),
            'eps' => array(
                'hammer_16x.eps',
                'hammer_32x.eps'
            ),
            'ico' => array(
                'hammer.ico'
            )
        )
    )
 */
```